# Is there some relation between characters in representation theory and multiplicative characters?

Tags: representation-theory, characters

A [character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_theory) of a [group representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation) is obtained by taking trace of each matrix in this representation.

The word character is often used in the sense that it is a homomorphism from a group to $(\mathbb C\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$ (sometimes with some additional properties). This kind of characters arises, e.g., in [Pontryagin duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality) or as [Dirichlet characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character) in number theory.

Is there some relation between these two (frequently used) meanings of the world character, or is it just a coincidence that the same word was used for both of them?

Comment: BTW only now I found out what [your gravatar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:3-adic_integers_with_dual_colorings.svg) is. (But I have to admit that I don't know anything about the mathematics behind it.)

Comment: Good work, detective. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A $1$-dimensional representation of a group is a continuous homomorphism into $\Bbb C^\times$: in particular it is equal to its own trace (once we identify $\mathrm{GL}_1(\Bbb C)\cong\Bbb C^\times$). So the group homomorphism definition of characters is the $1$-dimensional case of the trace-of-a-representation definition. To copy myself:

> The [homomorphisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_homomorphism) $G\to \Bbb C^\times$ are actually not the *whole* story of [character theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_theory), but are a very tidy chapter in it. If $V$ is a vector space (over $\Bbb C$) and $G$ finite, the homomorphisms $G\to  GL(V)$ from $G$ into the [general linear group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group) of invertible linear maps are called [*representations*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation), which are essentially the ways to equip $V$ with a linear $G$ [action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action). If $\rho$ is a representation, then the map given by $\chi_\rho:G\to \Bbb C:g\mapsto\mathrm{tr}\,\rho(g)$ (the [trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)) of the linear map associated to $g$, which is independent of basis or coordinate choice for $V$) is called a *character*.
>
> If $V$ is one-dimensional (in which case we call $\rho$ and $\chi_\rho$ one-dimensional as well) then $\rho=\chi_\rho$ and the characters are multiplicative. Note that $\mathrm{tr}\,\rho(e_G)=\dim\,V$ shows the dimension can be directly computed from the character, so there is no ambiguity with respect to what dimension a character may have. With a distinguished [basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) we have $V\cong \Bbb C^n$ in an obvious way, so we can write $GL(V)$ as $GL_n(\Bbb C)$, in which we are working with [*matrix*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) representations specifically.

(Over [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186822/what-is-an-irrreducible-character-of-a-finite-group/).)

Comment: Why just finite groups?

Comment: @Andrea - Erm, because I didn't want to bother writing "continuous" I guess.

Comment: @Andrea So far I have only learned about linear representations of finite groups. But maybe later I'll try to understand at least basics of some of other [branches of representation theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation#Branches_of_group_representation_theory).

Comment: Well, it seems to me that given any group $G$ and *any* homomorphism $\rho:G\rightarrow\Bbb C^\times$, then $\rho(g)=\text{tr}(\rho(g))$.

Comment: @Andrea, right. When a topology on $G$ is assumed and $G$ is infinite, I am not used to the noncontinuous homomorphisms $G\to GL(V)$ being admitted under the label "representation," though I have not studied representation theory this far anyway. Is it standard to accept noncontinuous homomorphisms as representations?

Comment: @anon : I was pointing out that the identity is purely algebraic, but I guess that you have a point here. I'm not properly a group/representation theorist, so I'm not able to give a qualified answer to your question whether (rephrasing) there exist interesting non-continuous representations. If memory doesn't betray me, all the representations I encountered this far are continuous. Should we maybe ask in SE? :)

Comment: @Andrea If you want, of course. I was speaking about the meaning of the word representation when applied to topological groups. According to [PM](http://planetmath.org/TopologicalGroupRepresentation.html) for instance, the homomorphism must be continuous by definition, and if my memory doesn't betray *me*, other sources also use this definition. Although technically if we only talk about group representations and not topological group representations we drop the continuity convention, so I guess I don't need to bother saying the homo is continuous. But hey.