# Noncommutative dual group

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups, noncommutative-algebra

If $G$ is a locally compact group, we can define its dual group $\hat G$. That is set of continuous homomorphism from $G$ to circle group $\mathbb T$. My question is how to define dual group $\hat G$ when $G$ is a noncommutative group?

Comment: There will be no dual group, which is a nicely structured collection of one-dimensional representations, since there will be representations that are more-dimensional. See [the "noncommutative theory" section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality#Non-commutative_theory) on Wikipedia's Pontryagin duality article. ([Also relevant](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186822/what-is-an-irrreducible-character-of-a-finite-group/).)

Comment: One meaning of $\hat{G}$ in the non-commutative case is the *unitary dual*, i.e., the set of unitary equivalence classes of irreducible representations of $G$ endowed with the Fell topology. It is the spectrum of the [group $C^\ast$-algebra $C^\ast(G)$.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_C%5E*-algebra#The_group_C.2A-algebra_C.2A.28G.29)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the "correct" generalization of the dual group to the noncommutative case is the unitary representation theory of $G$ (studying this reduces to studying homomorphisms into the circle group, or $\text{U}(1)$, when $G$ is commutative). At least when $G$ is compact, it is possible to recover $G$ from its unitary representation theory using some version of [Tannaka reconstruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannaka-Krein_duality), e.g. the Doplicher-Roberts theorem; this is the "correct" generalization of Pontrjagin duality to this case.

There are other possible generalizations; see [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70655/discrete-compact-duality-for-nonabelian-groups) for some.

Comment: It helps a lot. But I still confused what is the dual group, do you mean the dual group is set of unitary representation? Can you provide more information?

Comment: @owen: the dual group isn't a group. You can think of the correct "dual thing" as being the "moduli space" of unitary representations, but I prefer to work with the category of unitary representations (at least when $G$ is compact).